# Windows from c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I was messing with the properties section of my project then I tried to change the assembly name after I did it I started to getting error in every 5 sec. Then ı tried to change it back but it said an error occurred while loading the project's properties editor and I think I can fix it after a restart, but ıt never opened again.

The expression `"helo"+MSBuild ProjectName.Replace("", "_")`
cannot be evaluated. C:\Users\cagan OneDrive\Masaüstü\uyg\coding\pc_components\pc_c omponents.csproj

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open "C:\Users\cagan OneDrive\Masaüstü\uyg\coding\pc_components\pc_c omponents.csproj" this file with any text editor and change the assemblyname part again and build the project.